# OSX Mavericks shell mount NTFS network drive that has no share

Tags: bash, shell, osx-mavericks, mount

I migrated from Windows 7 to OSX. I am trying to recreate the functionality of "net use" on the Mac via Terminal. Problem is the machine I want to mount has no shares.

In Windows7 I could map the drive and have full access via:

```
 net use \\address\C$ /USER:user pass
```

Is there no bash method similar to this this?

```
rmdir /Volumes/test
mkdir /Volumes/test
mount_smbfs //user:pass@address/ /Volumes/test
```

Finally realized that the no shares was cause of my problem with that mounting.

Comment: Administrative shares should work the same with smbfs. You'd still need to specify the share name though:

`mount_smbfs //user:pass@address/C\$ /Volumes/test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably missed the `C$` part.

```
mount_smbfs '//user:pass@address/C$' /Volumes/test
```

Quoting (`''`) may not be necessary since `$` does not follow a parameter name but let's just be explicit.

You also need to add your username and password:

```
mount_smbfs '//user:pass@address/C$' /Volumes/test -o user='user',pass='pass'
```

Sometimes it doesn't work due to many causes I don't technically know but you can also try:

```
mount -t smbfs '//user:pass@address/C$' /Volumes/test -o user='user',pass='pass'
mount -t smbfs '//user:pass@address/C$' /Volumes/test -o username='user',password='pass'
mount -t cifs '//user:pass@address/C$' /Volumes/test -o user='user',pass='pass'
mount -t cifs '//user:pass@address/C$' /Volumes/test -o username='user',pass='password'
```

See [Mounting samba shares from a unix client](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Mounting_samba_shares_from_a_unix_client).

Comment: gives a "usage: mount_smbfs [-Nh] [-d mode] [-f mode] //[domain;][user[:password]@]server[/share] path" error


the -o flag isnt used apparently but other than that, this worked. it was the C$. could have sworn I had tried it as well before and it  didnt work but probably wrong.